# Decimal fraction to binary with precision

Tags: floating-point, binary, fractions

Consider the following fraction:

```
9.8765
```

How do I go about converting it to precise floating point binary without losing any value?

Now consider the following fraction

```
9.87654321
```

Again, how would I convert it to floating point binary without losing its value.

I want to determine how many exact binary bits are required to reconstruct the fraction from its floating point binary value.

This is just an example, I am looking to perform operations on large fractions with many digits (e.g. 9.876543210192283647582910).

Appreciate if the example would be in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no binary fraction that is exactly equal to any of your examples, so conversion to a binary floating point format will have rounding error. 9.87650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 is the closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary float to 9.8765. Is that close enough for your purposes?

Comment: You mean there will always be a rounding error when converting to and from fraction and binary? Can it be offset with more number of bits?

Comment: Every binary fraction has an exact decimal fraction equivalent. For example, every Java `double` number can be converted exactly to `BigDecimal`. Going the other way, more bits will allow closer approximation. That is why I asked whether 9.87650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 is close enough.

Comment: The number ⅓ cannot be written in decimal with a finite number of digits; it is .33333333… continuing forever. Similarly, 9.8765 cannot be written in binary with a finite number of digits. When you do the arithmetic to convert it, there is always a residue to continue to the next position. You can represent a decimal numeral accurately enough in binary that you can recover the original numeral, if you know how many digits it had. The number will have a small error, but it will be close enough to the original decimal numeral that you know which decimal numeral it came from.

Comment: However, when you do arithmetic on those numbers, their errors may compound (or may cancel). Then it may no longer be possible to figure out which decimal numeral would be the one you would obtain by doing decimal arithmetic instead of binary arithmetic. If you want to do decimal arithmetic, you should generally use software for decimal arithmetic, such as `BigDecimal`. If that is not suitable for your purpose, you need to add information to your question explaining the complete problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a rational number can be expressed as a radix R fraction if, and only if, in its lowest terms, all prime factors of the denominator are factors of R.

Applying this to decimal, a rational number has a terminating decimal expansion if, and only if, in its lowest terms 2 and 5 are the only prime factors of the denominator. Thus 13/40 has a terminating decimal expansion, 1/3 does not.

For binary fractions, that means expressing the rational as A/2<sup>B</sup> for integers A and B. Because 2 is a factor of 10, all binary fractions can be expressed as decimal fractions. 5 is not a factor of 2, so some decimal fractions such as 1/10 cannot be expressed as binary fractions.

There are additional conditions for exact representation as a normal Java `double`. B has to be in the range [-1022, 1023], and A must have no more than 53 significant bits. There are additional subnormal numbers, with exponent -1023. Increasing the number of bits would loosen those limits, but will still not allow numbers such as 1/10 to be expressed exactly in binary floating point.

The two commonest solutions are to live with it, or switch to `BigDecimal`.

9.87650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 is very, very close to 9.8765. For physical quantities such as lengths and weights, measurement error will dominate over conversion error even with good lab equipment. Of course, some algorithms will accumulate significant error due to rounding in subsequent calculations.

`BigDecimal` is particularly useful for numbers with terminating decimal expansions. Financial calculations often have to deal with exact multiples of 0.01 or 0.001. Although it allows arbitrary precision, up to available memory, it cannot avoid all rounding error. There is no `BigDecimal` that is exactly equal to 1/3.